# What happens when AWS secrets manager rotates a secret

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I'm exploring AWS secret manager for an upcoming project. I got a bit confused around the concept of rotating secrets. It seems I can only keep the secret for a specific duration and after that it will rotate. What happens once it gets rotated? Does the secrets value gets changed? For example, lets say I keep my mailgun access api in AWS secret manager which is `AB334Tfdxxss99`. If AWS secret manager changes it to something else, how can I send emails afterwards?

Comment: Rotation is optional. In the case of an external API key, you generally wouldn't use automated rotation unless Mailgun gives you a way to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Rotation is an optional feature only. Secrets Manager will never rotate your secrets unless you configure it to - [as per docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets.html).

From memory, this is mostly used with RDS, which due to an integration can rotate the database password and secret at the same time. As Ceejay points out below, custom rotation based on a lambda function is also an option.

Comment: Custom rotation is possible; Secrets Manager can invoke a Lambda function that does anything you like. If Mailgun supports generating a new API key, it would be possible to integrate it in this fashion.